# Equivalent of __func__ or __FUNCTION__ in Rust?

Tags: macros, rust

In C and C++ you can get the name of the currently executing function through the `__func__` macro with C99 & C++11 and `___FUNCTION___` for MSVC.

Is there an equivalent of this in Rust?

Example of `__func__` in C:

```c
#include "stdio.h"

void funny_hello() {
    printf ("Hello from %s\n", __func__);
}

int main() {
    funny_hello();
}
```

Outputs `Hello from funny_hello`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There was an [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/466) about this, but it was never agreed upon or implemented.

The rationale for its absence:

> "In general I don't think any of us have given an inordinate amount of
>   thought to these "debugging related" macros in terms of long term
>   stability. Most of them seem fairly harmless, but committing to
>   provide all of them for all Rust programs forever is a strong
>   commitment to make. We may want to briefly consider the story of these
>   macros in conjunction with considering adding this new macro."

Maybe Rust will have something comparable in the future,
but for now you will need to rely on your own tagging.

*side note:* `__FUNCTION__` is non standard, `__func__` exists in C99 / C++11.

Comment: A true shame ...

Answer (score 50):

You can hack one together with `std::any::type_name`.

```
macro_rules! function {
    () => {{
        fn f() {}
        fn type_name_of<T>(_: T) -> &'static str {
            std::any::type_name::<T>()
        }
        let name = type_name_of(f);
        name.strip_suffix("::f").unwrap()
    }}
}
```

Note that this gives a full pathname, so `my::path::my_func` instead of just `my_func`. [A demo is available.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=df5975cd589ae7286a769e1c70e7715d)

Comment: Please note that this implementation also has the limitation that it cannot currently be used to build static values, e.g: `static name : &'static str = function!();`

Comment: Note that this gives my::path::my_func::{{closure}} if my_func is an async fn.

Comment: `&name[..name.len() - 3].trim_end_matches("::{{closure}}")` would do the trick for `async fn`

Comment: @TeohHanHui That would hide normal closures too, not just the implicit async ones.

Comment: Please **don't do this**. From the documentation for [`type_name`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/fn.type_name.html): "The exact contents and format of the string returned are not specified, other than being a best-effort description of the type ... amongst the strings that `type_name::<Option<String>>()` might return are `Option<String>` and `std::option::Option<std::string::String>` ... the output may change between versions of the compiler."

Comment: @Shelvacu I think this poor advice to apply to debugging macros. Yes, you should be wary if general program correctness depends on the exact form given here, but for debugging? For something that's been basically stable for 7 years now and at most ends up in your logs? Go for it.

Answer (score 10):

Adding to [Veedrac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40234666/155423), you can get the function's name without its full path by adding this:

```rust
macro_rules! function {
    () => {{
        fn f() {}
        fn type_name_of<T>(_: T) -> &'static str {
            std::any::type_name::<T>()
        }
        let name = type_name_of(f);

        // Find and cut the rest of the path
        match &name[..name.len() - 3].rfind(':') {
            Some(pos) => &name[pos + 1..name.len() - 3],
            None => &name[..name.len() - 3],
        }
    }};
}
```

You will get `my_func` instead of `my::path::my_func` for example.

Answer (score 10):

It appears that `function_name` crate will do this.

https://docs.rs/function_name/latest/function_name/

The example from the docs is

```
use ::function_name::named;

#[named]
fn my_super_duper_function ()
{
    assert_eq!(
        function_name!(),
        "my_super_duper_function",
    );
}
```

I am not involved with the project and have not actually tried it yet.

Comment: I just tried this and it appears to work as advertised.

Comment: Seems to use a similar approach as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56723429/2441655

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [Alexis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63904992/12404989) there is a more idiomatic way to write this macro that also works inside rust async functions. Otherwise you will get `{{closure}}` in async function instead of real function name.

```
macro_rules! function {
    () => {{
        fn f() {}
        fn type_name_of<T>(_: T) -> &'static str {
            std::any::type_name::<T>()
        }
        type_name_of(f)
            .rsplit("::")
            .find(|&part| part != "f" && part != "{{closure}}")
            .expect("Short function name")
    }};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While there's a lack of official support, there's the [stdext crate](https://docs.rs/stdext/latest/stdext/macro.function_name.html) (also mentioned in the RFC [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2818#issuecomment-657822074)) that makes it easy to use.

```rust
use stdext::function_name;

fn foo() {
  println!("{}", function_name!());
}
```

This includes module/trait names, like `::module::Trait::function` if any.

If you only care about the name and not its entire path, you could do something like this for trait methods (keep in mind that there is runtime overhead for this, you may want to limit it with, e.g. [OnceCell](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/)):

```
let fn_name = function_name!()
              .rsplit_once(':')
              .expect("could not parse function name")
              .1;
```