# Rust: print the name of the function passed in as argument

Tags: rust

I'm trying to print out the args to the following function:

```
pub async fn loop_until_hit_rate_limit<'a, T, Fut>(
    object_arr: &'a [T],
    settings: &'a Settings,
    pool: &'a PgPool,
    f: impl Fn(&'a Settings, &'a PgPool, &'a T) -> Fut + Copy,
    rate_limit: usize,
) where
    Fut: Future<Output = anyhow::Result<()>>,
{
    // do stuff
    println!("args were: {}, {}, {}, {}, {}", object_arr, settings, pool, f, rate_limit) // <--- how do I make this work?
}
```

The naive approach fails with either this error (for {}):

```
 ^ `impl Fn(&'a Settings, &'a PgPool, &'a T) -> Fut + Copy` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
```

Or this error (for {:?}):

```
^ `impl Fn(&'a Settings, &'a PgPool, &'a T) -> Fut + Copy` cannot be formatted using `{:?}` because it doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`
```

Both of which make sense, but I'm not sure how to get around them. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088067/equivalent-of-func-or-function-in-rust) but it only prints the name of the calling function, not one passed in as arg.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You're trying to print a function ? Why ? What do you want the result to be ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret some sort of debugging thing I would expect, similar to printing callback names in a language like python or JS to know what the thing was called where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this?

Yes. You can get the name of any type with [`std::any::type_name`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/fn.type_name.html).

So you can do this:

```rust
pub async fn loop_until_hit_rate_limit<'a, T, Fut>(
    object_arr: &'a [T],
    settings: &'a Settings,
    pool: &'a PgPool,
    f: impl Fn(&'a Settings, &'a PgPool, &'a T) -> Fut + Copy,
    rate_limit: usize,
) where
    Fut: Future<Output = anyhow::Result<()>>,
{
    // do stuff
    fn type_name_of<T>(_: T) -> &'static str {
        std::any::type_name::<T>()
    }
    let f_name = type_name_of(f);
    println!("args were: {}, {}, {}, {}, {}", object_arr, settings, pool, f_name, rate_limit)
}
```

[simplified example in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9a5f2033ea83ecd421493335e3e83d83) with various kinds of functions