# How can I print functions as they are being called?

Tags: python, rust, trace, stack-trace

I am new in a large complicated codebase. I would like to follow a request as it is being processed. For this I'd like to have a feature that enables printing each function that is being called without having to add trace functionality everywhere in the codebase (see e.g. [crate trace](https://docs.rs/trace/latest/trace/)).

Ideally I would like exactly this python solution, but in rust (see [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8315566/5345715)):

```
def tracefunc(frame, event, arg, indent=[0]):
      if event == "call":
          indent[0] += 2
          print("-" * indent[0] + "> call function", frame.f_code.co_name)
      elif event == "return":
          print("<" + "-" * indent[0], "exit function", frame.f_code.co_name)
          indent[0] -= 2
      return tracefunc

import sys
sys.setprofile(tracefunc)

main()   # or whatever kicks off your script
```

**EDIT:**
A tool that does this may even be better. [See e.g. this solution for C++](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386747/tool-to-print-out-functions-being-called-during-run-time)

Comment: Have you tried using a debuger?

Comment: There's no such functionality in the rust source itself. There is [LLVM xray](https://www.llvm.org/docs/XRay.html), but afaik there's no support for it. Python is a dynamic language with an interpreter, which makes it **possible** to intercept function calls at runtime, but in a compiled language like Rust or C, it's not possible after the source code has been compiled.

Comment: "For this I'd like to have a feature that enables printing each function that is being called without having to add trace functionality everywhere in the codebase (see e.g. crate trace)." ah yes magic, I know some myself. You post the thing I was going to answer this question is so meaningless. https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/

Answer (score 1):

You could put a [`panic!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.panic.html) macro in your code, to get a backtrace.
You will also need to set the backtrace option with `export RUST_BACKTRACE=1` or `export RUST_BACKTRACE=full` before you execute your program (`cargo run`).

A way to get a live trace of a running Rust program is through logging. You might want to try the [`log`](https://crates.io/crates/log) crate, in conjunction with the [`syslog`](https://crates.io/crates/syslog) crate. Make use of the macros `debug!()`, `info!()`, `warn!()`, and `error!()` to log messages. You can use the [name of the current function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088067/equivalent-of-func-or-function-in-rust) if you wish.

Then configure `rsyslog` to route the messages from your application to a separate logfile, which you can monitor live with something like `tail -f /var/log/<yourapp.log>` in a separate terminal.