# Compile time values for debugging such as Module/Function/Line/File/etc

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I would like to add a custom logger feature to my Rust program. I would like to use the logger to help me debug any issues that arise with minimal details added to the `log` method.

What I would like to get is where the `log` method was executed within the code such as the module & function. Additional details if available would be nice such as file name and line number but not critical if that doesn't exist today.

Does the compiler create a variable during compilation that can be used as a constant within the code which will embed any/all of that information into the function call to the logger.

Something like this where `MODULE` & `FUNCTION` are compile time variables updated by the compiler.

```
logger.send(MODULE, FUNCTION, "Incorrect valued detected");
```

Comment: Why don't you use the [`log`](https://crates.io/crates/log) crate like everyone else?

Comment: You can get the [`file`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.file.html), [`line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.line.html), [`column`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.column.html) and [`module`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.module_path.html). Not sure about the function.

Comment: There is no equivalent `function_name!` but there appears to be a crate for it as you can see in [Equivalent of `__func__` or `__FUNCTION__` in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088067/equivalent-of-func-or-function-in-rust)